# Call a function when multipart transferTo method completes transfer

Tags: java, spring, multipart, file-transfer

I have created a function which takes a multipart file and using the Spring framework Multipart transferTo method transfers a file to a location on server. I want to call a function after the  completion of transfer. As sometimes file sizes are like 6 to 10 GB, other functions are getting called before the transfer completion.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#transferTo(java.io.File)

```
file.transferTo(somelocation)
```